# Compositing 2 images in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I intend to fit an image centered horizontally and vertically inside a J2ME form. However I couldn't find useful markup elements to do so. So I intend to create one totally transparent image the size of the form element and superimpose my intended image on it centered. And place the resulting image in the form (without using a canvas). I am looking for ways of doing this because my knowledge of J2ME is limited.

Any help, please?

```
public static Image CreateCompositeImage(Image oImage,int formWidth,int formHeight){

    final int imageWidth=oImage.getWidth();
    final int imageHeight=oImage.getHeight();
    int[] imge=new int[imageWidth*imageHeight];
    oImage.getRGB(imge,0,imageWidth,0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight);
    final int topMargin=(formHeight-imageHeight)/2;
    final int leftMargin=(formWidth-imageWidth)/2;
    final int pixelTop=topMargin*formWidth;

    int[] c=new int[formWidth*formHeight];
    int p=0, r=0;
    for (int i=0;i<pixelTop;i++){
        c[p++]=0xff000000;
    }
    for (int j=0;j<imageHeight;j++){
        for (int i=0;i<leftMargin;i++){
            c[p++]=0x880000ff;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<imageWidth;i++){
            c[p++]=imge[r++];
        }
        for (int i=0;i<leftMargin;i++){
            c[p++]=0x8800ff00;
        }
    }
    int pixelBottom=formWidth*formHeight-p;
    for (int i=0;i<pixelBottom;i++){
        c[p++]=0xffffffff;
    }
    return Image.createRGBImage(c,formWidth,formHeight,true);
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. If it was me, I would probably make a class `PaddedImage` extending `Image`, and then generate the padded image like that.
The constructor should receive the width of the `Displayable` and the path to the file. Then create two images, one from the file path and one using the width of the `Displayable` and height of the file-image. Then retrive the `Graphics` object of the bigger image, and draw the other image onto it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have put togather some code that reads an image into an integer array; and also created another array for the composite image and tried to add padding around the imput image. The result is I get the top and bottom paddings; left and right paddings are not visible and the center image is skewed. Trying to fix the skweness. Odly enough it looks right on the emulator but skewed on actual devices. Here is the code

Comment: Ah sorry some colors are changed from transparent to colored for tests.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to create new class that inherits from CustomItem, or to use a Canvas instead of the Form.

In both cases you override the paint() method.
There you get a Graphics-Object. You use this object do do your drawing.
Especially for you it has a drawImage() method, where you can just put in the position.
You then need no pixel data manipulation.

Overriding CustomItem or Canvas is something you do often in Java-me programming, so it is worth learn it.

Comment: It would make sense to use a canvas had I not used forms throughout the whole app. The composite image that I want to make is meant to have transparent background. I am not sure, but can I get transparent background using a canvas?

Comment: Hello again everyone. Mission accomplished. Thank you mr_lou and Mr. Meier for caring to join.

Comment: Mission accomplished, but I want to ask something if you guys are still there. After I create an image from the int array what happens to the int array of the image ( c[p++] ). Does it automatically get erased or do I manually set it to null or what.

Comment: Normally you ask a second question on stack overflow. Your int array is in a local variable, so it will garbage collected in Java, and you don't need to do anything.